# Drive API access with a Service Account and "Allow users to install Google Drive apps" unchecked

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an app engine application that requests to Drive API in a Google Apps Domain with a Service Account. When I try I get this error "The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps". I don't want to enable "Allow users to install Google Drive apps" in domain admin console because any domain user can install any application and this access to his domain data if grants access. I want that only my app engine application can access to the API but not the others.

Anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to enable a single app to be installed. If your app is a Marketplace app, you can auto [deploy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482?hl=en) it for any user on your organization. We're working on a feature to provide the same organization-wide deployment feature for Chrome Web Store apps.